rules for nested nodes in Firebase Realtime
I can't manage roles correctly for Firebase Realtime Database, I would like the data entered by the admin to be able to be read by everyone and the data entered by the user user to be seen only by the user who has auth.uid equal to idUser, I did lots of different tests but the only result I managed to obtain is either everyone sees everything or nobody sees nothing.
Database:

services
    -JKkhjghjjlhk55454 // this is servicesId
        category: "veterinarian"
        idUser: "GHkJjkhg54GGG"
        roleIns:"user"
    -Hkhfhgh64545ddddddd
        category: "veterinarian"
        idUser: "Hhjhgjhg455545e"
        roleIns:"admin"

users
    Hhjhgjhg455545e // this is uid
        name: "John"
        role: "admin"
    GHkJjkhg54GGG
        name: "Anie"
        role: "user"

Rules:
{
  "rules": {
    "services": { 
        ".read": "data.child('$servicesId').child('idUser').val() == auth.uid || data.child('$servicesId').child('roleIns').val() == 'admin'"
    }
  }
}


The '$servicesId' in your rules won't work for two reasons:

You never actually define a capture variable anywhere
You're writing it as a string

Fixing those, leads to:
{
  "rules": {
    "services": { 
      "$servicesId": { // 
        ".read": "data.child('idUser').val() == auth.uid || data.child('roleIns').val() == 'admin'"
      }
    }
  }
}

So now we've declared the rule one level deeper, on the actual individual service node, and thus can access the data of idUser and roleIns directly under it.

Keep in mind, you can't just try to read all services from the client - as rules are not filters.

Thanks, i made the changes you recommended, but nothing has changed, it's like before. Either everyone sees everything or no one sees anything.

First off, does it makes sense what I answered so far - and why both of those would keep your initial solution from working? --- Second: there may be more mistakes in the code, but the ones I pointed out in my answer were definitely some of them. --- Third: it's impossible to say what else is going wrong, without also seeing the minimal code and the actual JSON data (as text) that are needed to reproduce the problem. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your Firebase Database console.

Now I exported the json as you told me to do, and I see all the records.

I think I'll have to manage everything from the client, because it's not possible from the server, the rules don't work :-(
